# What is the default username for SSH EC2 Linux instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

What is the default user name for the SSH EC2 amazon Linux instance. I have an old instance and I forgot the username. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For Ubuntu instance, it is `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 40):

For Amazon Linux, it's `ec2-user`

Comment: For some reason this was the only answer I could find to this question after about 10 minutes of looking.  Thanks!

Comment: find more here https://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username/